# Why some forms are sent as attachments in HTML format instead of PDF?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have created approximately 10 forms in Cognito Forms and they all being sent via email as a PDF attachment with the exception of 2 of them which are HTML.

I have not been able to determine why they are attached as a HTML v. PDF.

Any help is appreciated.